# Tropical Fish Commands

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Does anyone know how to spawn a specific kind of tropical fish?

Answer (score 4):

This command will always spawn the same type of fish and the fish will never despawn (Which you probably don´t want to happen in your aquarium)

```
/summon minecraft:tropical_fish <position> {PersistenceRequired: 1b,Variant: <number>}
```

You can calculate your variant with this formula:

```
((256*<pattern color>+<base color>)*256+<pattern>)*256+<size>
```

or

```
  <pattern color> * 16777216
+ <base color> * 65536
+ <pattern> * 256
+ <size>
```

According to [this](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Tropical_Fish#Names) the numbers for the `pattern color` and the `base color` are these:

> 0 for white
> 1 for oange
> 2 for maenta
> 3 for sky (cyan blue)
> 4 for yellow
> 5 for lime
> 6 for rose
> 7 for gray
> 8 for silver
> 9 for teal
> 10 for plum
> 11 for blue
> 12 for brown
> 13 for green
> 14 for red

The pattern has the numbers 0-5, left to right
The size is either 0, for the bottom row, or 1 for the upper row:

[image: All 12 different kinds of fish]

Comment: There's a website that can calculate the variant for you!! It's https://www.soltoder.com/MCFishVariants/